# How to retain the scroll bar position of primefaces pickList on update?

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I am working on JSF Application i am trying to retain the  position of  pickList scrollbar in Primefaces 6.2 version,since i am updating the pickList component on transfer event it does not retain in the same scrolled position.
Below is my code

.xhtml

```
<p:pickList id="pkListUserTeam" value="#{salesTeamService.userPickList}" 
                var="user" converter="picklistConverter"  responsive="true"
                itemLabel="#{user.userName}" itemValue="#{user}" style="width: 460px">
        <f:facet name="sourceCaption">Users</f:facet>
        <f:facet name="targetCaption">#{custom.labels.get('IDS_TEAM_MEMBERS')}</f:facet>
           <p:ajax event="transfer" listener="#{salesTeamService.onMemberTransfer}"  onstart="PF('syncProcessDlg').show();"  update=":frmSalesTeamMembers:msgs" />
    </p:pickList>
```

Below is my java code where i update pickList component on event.isRemove() method

```
public void onMemberTransfer(TransferEvent event) {
        System.out.println("onMemberTransfer==>"+event);
        List<Integer> usersToSync = new ArrayList<>();
        //action to be performed when a member(s) is added
        if (event.isAdd()) {
            for (Object user : event.getItems()) {
                Users u = (Users) user;
                SalesGroupTeam sgt = new SalesGroupTeam();
                sgt.setSgtSmanId(selectedSalesTeam.getSmanId());
                sgt.setSgtMemberId(u.getUserId());
                sgt.setSgtCommPct(BigDecimal.ZERO);
                // Shreejith 30/07/2018
                sgt.setSgtContSyncFlag(0);
                sgt.setSgtCrmOnlyFlag(0);
                salesGroupTeamDao.saveSalesGroupTeam(sgt);
                u.setUserName(u.getUserName());
                saveDefaultTeamMember(selectedSalesTeam.getSmanId(), u.getUserId());
                u.setDefaultSalesTeam(selectedSalesTeam.getSmanId());             //Set Default Sales team for user
                usersToSync.add(u.getUserId());
                //reSyncGoogleContacts(u.getUserId());              //#492935: RSTTHERMAL: Commenting as sync process will be run later
            }

            Message.addMessage("Member(s) Added", Message.severity.INFO);
        }
        //action to be performed when a member(s) is removed
        if (event.isRemove()) {
            System.out.println("REMOVE>>>");
            for (Object user : event.getItems()) {
                Users u = (Users) user;
                salesGroupTeamDao.deleteTeamMember(u.getUserId(), selectedSalesTeam.getSmanId());
                salesMemberVisibilityDao.delete(selectedSalesTeam.getSmanId(), u.getUserId(), true);
                usersToSync.add(u.getUserId());
//                reSyncGoogleContacts(u.getUserId());          //#492935: RSTTHERMAL: Commenting as sync process will be run later
                u.setDefaultSalesTeam(selectedSalesTeam.getSmanId());             //Set Default Sales team for user
            }
            //  Bug #5700: values not added in users when removed from memebers  1/09/21 by harshithad
            loadUsers();
            PrimeFaces.current().ajax().update("frmSalesTeamMembers:salesTeamTab:pkListUserTeam");
            Message.addMessage("Member(s) Removed", Message.severity.INFO);
        }

        //#492935: RSTTHERMAL: SalesTeams don't take users on 1 click
        //When multiple users are added or removed from sales team at once, process takes time. So added a dialog to inform user that process is going on
        if (!usersToSync.isEmpty()) {
            int totalUsersToSync = usersToSync.size();
            int count = 1;
            for (Integer user : usersToSync) {
                if (count++ == totalUsersToSync) {
                    //Hide the dialog when the sync process runs for the last user
                    PrimeFaces.current().executeScript("PF('syncProcessDlg').hide();");
                    //RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().execute("PF('syncProcessDlg').hide();");
                }
                reSyncGoogleContacts(user);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Why do you update the list? I see no change to `userPickList`.

Comment: I am trying to sort the list in alphabetical order on remove event .Hence i update `userPickList`